# Linux IO operator '>'

Tags: linux

I have cronjob as `jstack > error.log` every second to get the snapshot of error.

My problem is if I use `>` operator in linux does it close file also or keep the file open?

Comment: Whats the problem, look for open files in system and check if the file is still open, `lsof |  grep <your filename>`. You will get the answer. 
Though it would be closed, but I am sure if you are running it everysec, it wont run every sec.. Cron deamon comes to see cronjob every minute by default. So its too much to ask from cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats the problem, look for open files in system and check if the file is still open, `lsof | grep <your filename>`. You will get the answer.

Though it would be closed, just to be sure you can do that.

**NOTE: I am sure if you are running it every sec, it wont run every sec.. Cron daemon comes to see cronjob every minute by default. So its too much to ask from cron.**

Comment: Thanks its was really helpful for me

Answer (score 5):

You're going to overwrite the file every second.

You might want `jstack >> error.log`.